# RadioButtonList select value from class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have RadioButtonList1 with item "Accept" and "Reject" as shown in code

```
 <tr>
        <td width="30%">
            <b>Status:</b>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem Value="lAccept">Accept</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="lReject">Reject</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList1"  TargetControlID="RadioButtonList1"  ErrorMessage="Status is Required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  </td>
```

Now in back end i want to select Reject automatically inside the below condition.

```
  if ((RQ >= 2 && RQ <= 8) && RejQ>0)
    {

    }
```

How i will select value of RadioButtonList1 in class? 
Thanks in Advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select the given index. Write this line in Page_Load event to select it automatically!!

```
RadioButtonList1.Items[1].Selected = true;
```